# python versions, setup.py, python alias, nose

Tags: python, macos, nose

I've seen quite a few posts on this topic, but there seems to be little agreement or definitive answer. I understand that OSX (in my case 10.10.5) comes with Python2.7 installed, as detailed in the [official python docs](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/).

After following those instructions, I now have python 2.7 and python 3.4 installed (accessible by `$ python` and `$ python3`, respectively) and perhaps more versions. I find python versions in a few places:

- `/Applications/Python 3.4`
- `/usr/local/bin` (contains `python`, `python2`, `python2.7`, `python3`, `python3.4`
- `/usr//bin` (contains `python2.6`, `python2.7`)
- `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions` (contains `2.3`, `2.5`, `2.6`, `2.7`, `Current`)

Moreover, I'm still having trouble when I install python packages...and I think it's because I don't completely understand where certain packages are installed, their PATH variables and how they are aliased.

Problem:

For example, after successfully installing `nose` with `pip install nose`, I cannot use `$ nosetests` because the command is not found.

Suggested solutions:

- Inspect the `nose` directories and look for `nosetests` to alias it (but despite there being many other files within `/nose`, regardless of the version, there isn't anything about `nosetests`).
- Another suggestion is to run `python setup.py install` within `/nose` but that simply gives this error:

  `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
- Some posts suggested simply using sudo as a fix to the problem...but I have been warned against using sudo without understanding why I need it, and the nose docs don't mention needing sudo, so I don't want to simply put a band-aid over a deeper issue that may arise later.

Comment: I would suggest that you use `virtualenv`s to manage interpreters and dependencies on a project-by-project basis; this can also help when you're distributing, as e.g. `pip freeze > requirements.txt` doesn't contain a bunch of irrelevant packages. See e.g. http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/

Answer (score 1):

My original question was basically two questions: one about conflicting versions of python and the other about installing the `nose` package specifically.

For the first question, I found jonrsharpe's initial comment to my question very helpful. He links to [a tutorial that explains virtualenv](http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/) and how to set it up. However, I was still uncertain how to install packages only within that `virtualenv`, because even when I'm in the `virtualenv` directory and I `pip install`, the package is still listed under `pip freeze` when outside of that `virtualenv` directory.

Solution:

[This tutorial was helpful in further explaining `virtualenv`](http://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/), what it is and how to use it. In short, `virtualenv` creates a copy of `python` in the designated `virtualenv` directory that has its OWN `pip`. That local `pip` must be used to install packages locally for that `virtualenv`, referencing it as `[virtualenv_dir_you_created]/bin/pip install nose`

And, by using `virtualenv`, problems with permission for writing to packages globally disappear.